# Filtrar csv con grep ERE un rango de edades

Tags: csv, grep, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo un csv con el formato:

```
user,gender,age,native_languaje,other_lang
```

Necesito, mediante un comando grep de tipo ERE filtrar con las siguientes condiciones y una de ellas me está dando problema, no consigo unir ambos rangos.

- Edad comprendida entre los rangos de edad de 10 a 19 años y de 30
  a 39, ambos inclusive.

Consigo que me filtre los dos rangos por separado, pero no en una única expresión.

Es decir, para el rango 10 a 19 años uso esta sentencia y me funciona.

```
grep -E '(.*),(.*),[1][0-9],(.*),(.*)' fichero.csv
```

y de igual modo con

```
grep -E '(.*),(.*),[3][0-9],(.*),(.*)' fichero.csv
```

Pero, ¿Cómo podría unirlas y que admita los dos rangos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente une `[1]` y `[3]` y déjalo en `[13]`:

```
grep -E '(.*),(.*),[13][0-9],(.*),(.*)' fichero
#                   ^^
```

`[X]` se lee como: cualquiera dentro de los caracteres que hay dentro de `[]`. Por tanto, `[13]` es *o bien 1, o bien 3*.

Por tanto, `[13][0-9]` coincide con cualquier número de la forma XY, donde X puede ser 1 o 3 y luego Y puede ser cualquier número entre 0 y 9. Resultado: de 10 a 19 y de 30 a 39.

Comment: Mil gracias! Probé con comas y no había manera. Conseguido!! :)

Comment: @Maggie genial! Considera aceptar la respuesta, tal y como se explica en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: gracias de nuevo @ferdoqui, no sabía como aceptarla y no registraba mi voto positivo por no tener reputación!